# Sed command in Linux. how to replace character starting wih xxx and ending with yyy with another string

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to replace all occurrences of a string starting with `B00` and ending with `\` with another string `customdata`. How can I do that?

I tried:

```
sed -i 's/BOO\*\\/customdata/' file.txt.
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't escape the `*` and use `[^\\]*` to not skip over `\`:

```
sed -i 's/BOO[^\\]*\\/cusomdata/g' file.txt.
```

If you want to preserve the delimiters, don't capture the trailing `\` and put BOO back:

```
sed -i 's/BOO[^\\]*/BOOcusomdata/g' file.txt.
```

Comment: It should be `s/BOO.*\\/cusomdata/g`. OP wants to replace all the occurrences of a string.

Comment: its working...but what if i only want to replace the character which comes between B00 and first occurence of \ .. for example my string in B00JKLJALK\somedata\abac\   and i want to replace it with customasindata\somedata\abac\

Comment: Then replace it with `B00customasindata\\ `

Comment: i didn't got it what you mean by replace it with B00customasindata\